# Check to see if my isomorphism is correct

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-isomorphism

Is multiplication modulo $10$ isomorphic to addition modulo $4$?

$U(10) = \{1,3,7,9\}$,
the identity is $1$,
it is a cyclic group of order $4$, with generator $3$.

$\Bbb Z_4 = \{0,1,2,3\}$, 
the identity is $0$,
it is a cyclic group of order $4$

\begin{gather*}
1 \mapsto 0 \\
3 \mapsto 1 \\
9 \mapsto 2 \\
7 \mapsto 3
\end{gather*} 
(Is this map sufficient to show multiplication mod $10$ is isomorphic to addition mod $4$?

Comment: You just need to check that the set map you have defined is a group homomorphism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As IBWiglin says in the comments, you need to check that this map $f$ is a group homomorphism. That means for every $a,b \in U(10)$ you need to check $f(ab) = f(a) + f(b)$. You can easily check that it is true here.

More generally if $a,b$ are coprime numbers, then $U(ab) \cong U(a) \times U(b)$ and $U(p)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{p-1}$ for every prime number $p$. So in your case:
$$\begin{align*}
U(10) & \cong U(2) \times U(5) \\
& \cong \mathbb{Z}_1 \times \mathbb{Z}_4 \\
& \cong \mathbb{Z}_4
\end{align*}$$